# plotly's line_group analog in seaborn

Tags: python, plotly, seaborn

The function [`plotly.express.line`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line.html) has an argument that is `line_group` which allows to specify one column to determine each individual line. I am looking to replicate this behavior with seaborn, so far without success.

This is how my pandas data frame looks like:

```
                Time (s)  Amplitude (V)  n_trigger signal_name
n_waveform                                                    
3           0.000000e+00       0.001249          1     MCP-PMT
3           5.000000e-11       0.001379          1     MCP-PMT
3           1.000000e-10       0.001558          1     MCP-PMT
3           1.500000e-10       0.001764          1     MCP-PMT
3           2.000000e-10       0.002313          1     MCP-PMT
...                  ...            ...        ...         ...
3332        1.985000e-08       0.004731       1666         DUT
3332        1.990000e-08       0.004847       1666         DUT
3332        1.995000e-08       0.005053       1666         DUT
3332        2.000000e-08       0.004916       1666         DUT
3332        2.005000e-08       0.004648       1666         DUT
```

Using plotly like this

```py
fig = px.line(
    data_frame = waveforms.reset_index(drop=False).sort_values(['n_waveform','Time (s)']),
    x = 'Time (s)',
    y = 'Amplitude (V)',
    color = 'signal_name',
    line_group = 'n_waveform',
)
```

I get the desired plot, which looks like this:

[image]

With seaborn I have this code

```py
sns.lineplot(
    data = waveforms,
    x = 'Time (s)',
    y = 'Amplitude (V)',
    hue = 'signal_name',
)
```

which produces this

[image]

How can I tell it not to aggregate the data in the y axis, and use the `n_waveform` column to create individual lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `units` parameter

```
df = sns.load_dataset("fmri").query("region == 'frontal'")
sns.lineplot(
    data=df,
    x="timepoint", y="signal", hue="event", units="subject",
    estimator=None, lw=1,
)
```

[image]